# SSRS 2008 R2 Report:Each row from different server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

There are multiple servers for each country.We want to create the report that displays the count of each country like below

[image]

```
Select 'UK' as Region,Pending Cards,Active Cards 
from Cardorder where month='June'
```

How to retrieve the results from different server for each row in SSRS?

Comment: Can you combine the data into one query using the union operator?

Comment: Each Region is from different server.We don't have linked server too,So i can't use union operator in sqlserver

Comment: If you can't solve it with SQL try this approach http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31414.ssrs-merge-data-from-different-datasources-into-one-dataset-inside-ssrs-report.aspx

Comment: What you are really asking here is "How do I combine data from two different SQL Servers" to which the answer in eloquently described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918259/how-to-fetch-data-from-two-different-sql-servers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you, if you cannot set up linked servers. You need to run this in sqlcmd mode (SSMS 2016) or from console and can collect the desired data. I would recommend to store the data in a temporary table to generate the reports.

```
:connect server_uk -l 120 -U username -P pasword
Select 'UK' as Region,Pending Cards,Active Cards 
from DATABASE.SCHEMA.Cardorder where month='June'
union
:connect server_us -l 120 -U username -P pasword
Select 'US' as Region,Pending Cards,Active Cards 
from DATABASE.SCHEMA.Cardorder where month='June'
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to setup linked servers, especially if you will be creating more queries and creating more reports using this data. The query would look like the following:

```
Select 'UK' as Region,Pending Cards,Active Cards 
from db1.[databasename].[schema].Cardorder where month='June'
UNION
Select 'US' as Region,Pending Cards,Active Cards 
from db2.[databasename].[schema].Cardorder where month='June'
UNION
Select 'IND' as Region,Pending Cards,Active Cards 
from db3.[databasename].[schema].Cardorder where month='June'
```

and so forth.....